# How to fit widgets within frame in python

Tags: python, widget, pyqt, maya

I am pretty new at python but currently I am getting some problem here with the part where I am unable to get my stuff fit within the width of the window.
I am trying to set it in such a way that it is:
 Eg. Name         Button

by the way, I am using Maya to integrate and run my stuff.

If I set it to central, it fits but it is all over the place as I only wanted it to occupy a portion only. So are there any ways for me to fit it nicely into it?
By the way, if its possible, can it be done using my current codings?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sip
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui 
import os

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):   
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.resize(400,800)
        self.setWindowTitle("GetShots")
        self.pubDock = SetShotInfo()
        self.pubDW = QDockWidget(self.tr(""), self)
        self.pubDW.setWidget(self.pubDock)
       # self.setCentralWidget(self.pubDW)

def getMayaWindow():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return sip.wrapinstance(long(ptr), QObject)

def main():
    global app
    global form
    app = qApp
    form = MainWindow(getMayaWindow())
    form.show() 

class GetShot(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, display=None):
        QFrame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.createWidgets()
        self.createLayout()      

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.showLabel = QLabel('Show')
        self.showName = QLineEdit()

        self.showName.setText(str(os.environ['SHOW']))

        self.shotLabel = QLabel('Shot Filter')
        self.shotName = QLineEdit()
        self.showButton = QPushButton('Set Show')
        self.showButton.setMaximumWidth(200)
        self.shotButton = QPushButton('Filter Shots')
        self.shotButton.setMaximumWidth(200)

        self.rootLabel = QLabel('Change Root')
        self.rootButton = QComboBox()

    def createLayout(self):       
        # Sets the Layout of Show and Shot
        setShowLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        setShowLayout.addWidget(self.showLabel)
        setShowLayout.addWidget(self.showName)
        setShowLayout.addWidget(self.showButton)

        setShotLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        setShotLayout.addWidget(self.shotLabel)
        setShotLayout.addWidget(self.shotName)
        setShotLayout.addWidget(self.shotButton)

        # Sets the Change Root Layout
        chgRootLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        chgRootLayout.addWidget(self.rootLabel)
        chgRootLayout.addWidget(self.rootButton)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addLayout(setShowLayout)
        mainLayout.addLayout(setShotLayout)
        mainLayout.addLayout(chgRootLayout)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is `SetShotInfo()` inside `__init__()` of `MainWindow` class?

Comment: I used that to call out the widgets so that it will display when executed. Unless I am placing/writing it wrongly?

Comment: I recommend you to use *QtDesigner* to create your mainWindow and arrange it's contents (widgets) because you are creating lot of widgets. That will be easy for you to arrange the contents of mainWindow.

Comment: I tried to use QtDesigner, but as soon as I convert the code, I'm getting more lost as the list is pretty huge. Not to mention that as I am going to create some database links, let's just say, the format in QtDesigner seems different from the way I code?

Comment: I managed to run your code without Maya and using the `self.setCentralWidget` does exactly what I expect it to do. I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. Do you not want the DockWidget to occupy all space?

Comment: Hi Yeray, when i run my code, as I set my Main Window in the size of (400,800), instead of occupying the whole width, it only occupies 60% of it. Is there anyway I can make it to fill the width?

I understand that pubdock may not be the best option for it, but if it needs to be change, please do advice

Comment: [This](http://i43.tinypic.com/63w45w.jpg) is what I get simply uncommenting your `self.setCentralWidget(self.pubDW)`, do you not get that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Layouts, combine [vertical](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qvboxlayout.html) and [horizontal](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qhboxlayout.html) and play with the [size policy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qsizepolicy.html) of the widgets to fit them as you need.

Here's a quick example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class ButtonContainer(QtGui.QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(ButtonContainer, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry( 150, 150, 650, 350)
    btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Name button', self)
    btn.setSizePolicy( QtGui.QSizePolicy( QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed ) )
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget( btn )
    self.setLayout(vbox)
    self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = ButtonContainer()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The commenters are right in suggesting *QtDesigner*, if you'd rather code it yourself at least have a mock up *ui* file where you can play interactively with the layouts and size policies, it's really helpful.